# MySQL error because of syntax in Custom PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to enter user's data into a database. I think the commas in the address are causing the error.

```
<?php 
 $full_name = $_POST["fullname"]; 
 $email = $_POST["email"]; 
 $password = $_POST["password"]; 
 $full_address = $_POST["address"]; 
 $city = $_POST["city"]; 
 $age = $_POST["age"]; 
 $contact_number = $_POST["number"]; 
 $gender = $_POST["gender"]; 
 $education = $_POST["education"]; 

?>

<?php
$servername = "hidden";
$username = "hidden";
$password = "hidden";
$dbname = "hidden";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education)
VALUES ($full_name, $email, $password,$full_address,$city,$age,$contact_number,$gender,$education)";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Look into PDO, this is rife with potential SQL injections.

Comment: +1 PDO is the way to go. Using combination of `sprintf()` and `addslashes()` is a poor-man's SQL injection attack protection which is better than nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should consider using parameterized queries:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, password, full_address, city, age, contact_number, gender, education)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);

// Bind parameters
$stmt->bind_param("s", $full_name);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $password);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $full_address);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $age);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $contact_number);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $gender);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $education);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

For more information refer to the PHP manual on [MySQLi prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Remove the parameter from `execute()`. I have fixed it in my code example.

Comment: Do I have to keep the `INSERT` query as it is (with the ? in them) or I have to replace them with my variables?

Comment: Yes you keep the insert query as-is with `?` placeholders. Your variables are bound using [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: I have a question. Why didn't you use `mysqli_prepare()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote string in your SQL statement;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (full_name, email, password,full_address,city,age,contact_number,gender,education)
VALUES ('$full_name', '$email', '$password','$full_address','$city',$age,'$contact_number','$gender','$education')";
```

Notice the single quotes around all the variables that contain strings. I might be a bit off because I don't know the values or table structure. 
But the just quote all values that are going in to a Date or Text field.

To avoid additional problems and security risks you should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` (at a minimum).

In all your assignment statements wrap the values in `mysqli_real_escape_string`

```
$full_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["fullname"]); 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
...
```

Note this requires setting up your DB connection before the variable assignments, so you'll have to reorganize your code a bit.

rink.attendant.6's answer is the proper way to adapt your code.

Comment: OP is using mysqli, and should be using bound parameters instead; just putting quotes around the values will fail if there are apostrophes in the data, and leaves the code wide open to SQL injection

Comment: [`mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["fullname"])`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33287612/2) that requires a db connection as the first parameter http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: I personally wouldn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` since it, as mentioned above, requires active database connection and **requires network round-trip** which will bite you back when mysql is not localhost but other server in different availability zone.